# Makefile compilation in c / relocation R_X86_64_32S

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, makefile, fpic

Today i want to compile my project with a Makefile (im in Ubuntu 17) but i have a really big problem :

> /usr/bin/ld: ./lib/my/libgnl.a(gnl.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompilé avec -fPIC
>   /usr/bin/ld : échec de l'édition de liens finale : Section non-représentable sur la sortie
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Makefile:52 : la recette pour la cible « mysh » a échouée
>   make: *** [mysh] Erreur 1

I've been trying to find a solution for over an hour, but now I'm starting to lose it. (yeah i already had the -fPIC flag in my Makefile)
Can you help me please ?

There is my Makefile : [MAKEFILE part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvP8Y.jpg)
[MAKEFILE part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLrkx.jpg)

```
SRC     = source/utils/char_utils.c \
        source/utils/clean_str.c \
        source/utils/check_redir.c \
        source/utils/count_words.c \
        source/utils/my_get_array.c \
        source/utils/my_get_number.c \
        source/utils/my_strncat.c \
        source/utils/my_strcat.c \
        source/utils/my_strcmp.c \
        source/utils/my_strdup.c \
        source/utils/my_strncmp.c \
        source/utils/my_strcpy.c \
        source/utils/my_str_to_wordtab.c \
        source/core/check_spaces.c \
        source/core/error_exec.c \
        source/core/handle_signals.c                
        source/core/my_builtin.c \
        source/core/my_cd.c \
        source/core/my_commas.c \
        source/core/my_env.c \
        source/core/my_exec.c \
        source/core/my_exit.c \
        source/core/my_getenv.c \
        source/core/my_prompt.c \
        source/core/my_pipe.c \
        source/core/my_d_redir_left.c \
        source/core/my_d_redir_right.c \
        source/core/my_redir_left.c \
        source/core/my_redir_right.c \
        source/core/my_parsing.c \
        source/core/my_setenv.c \
        source/core/my_unsetenv.c \
        source/core/my_shell.c \
        source/core/main.c
OBJ     =       $(SRC:.c=.o)

NAME    =       mysh

CFLAGS  =       -fPIC -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Iinclude

all:    $(NAME)

$(NAME):        $(OBJ)
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(SRC) -lgnl -L./lib/my

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
        rm -f $(NAME)
        find -name "*~" -delete
        find -name "#*#" -delete
        find -name "vgcore*" -delete

re:     fclean all

.PHONY: fclean clean all re
```

Comment: I'd repost the error in English [google translate can/did translate it from French]. Also, I'd post your Makefile. But, it appears you're trying to create a shared object [.so] and that you can't use the `.bss` section (unitialized data) in it. From "mysh", I infer that you're just trying to create a program, so I'm not sure why the final target is a shared library. Are you using `-r`?

Comment: The goal of my project is to make a shell. 
Here I just want to compile my different files with a library including a function but it's when compiling the library that it bugs

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. You're creating a `.a` [_static_ library] and then linking to it to get the final shell program. It's the final step that has the issue. It probably doesn't need `-fPIC` and that's the clue that there is an extraneous option that is causing the linker to claim that it needs `-fPIC`. Again, please post your Makefile

Comment: Ok i gonna update my post.

Comment: its good you can check

Comment: Please post the Makefile as text rather than an image.

Comment: How can i this ? im new in stack overflow

Comment: its done im sorry for the visual

Comment: In your editor, do a select all text, then copy. You can then click edit on your post, and do a code block, (i.e. the `{}` icon), and then a paste

Comment: thx its done !!

Comment: Remove the `-fPIC`. It's extraneous and [probably] the source of your problems. Also, in your `gcc` line, replace `$(SRC)` with `$(OBJ)`. Notice that you have `$(NAME): $(OBJ)` as your target, so you want `$(OBJ)` in your `gcc` line.

Comment: With those changes, you may need a `%.o: %.c` target/rule for your `.o` files.

Comment: What I don't understand is that it worked before I was on Ubuntu. (Fedora 27)

Comment: And i add the -fPIC because i read a lot of forum where there is this problem and people said this flag can resolve the problem